# [Flutter/RiverPod 2.0]: How to correct handle status of the added item to DataBase

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I am new in Flutter and RiverPod, I am trying to learn these technologies.

*What I want to do.
User click button 'Add' it shows new Screen 'Add Item'.
Screen 'Add Item' has input and button 'Add New Item'
After User click button 'Add New Item' it navigates to Item List with added item. *

So, detailed.
**RiverPod Side: **

```
class Items extends AutoDisposeAsyncNotifier<List<Item>> {

  @override
  FutureOr<List<Item>> build() {
    return ref.watch(dataBaseProvider).getAllUsers();
  }

  FutureOr<void> addItem(Item item) async {
    final apiItem = await ApiGet().geTitle();
    ref.read(dataBaseProvider).insertUser(item.copyWith(items: apiItem));
  }
}

final allItemsProvider = AsyncNotifierProvider.autoDispose<Items, List<Item>>(() {
  return Items();
}, name: 'Items'.toUpperCase());
```

**AddItemScreen - a button part: **

```
  Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: OutlinedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    final user = Item(name: _itemName.text);
                    ref.read(allItemsProvider.notifier).addUser(user);

                    if (context.mounted) {
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                      ref.invalidate(allItemsProvider);
                    }
                  },
                  child: const Text(
                    'Add New Item',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                  )),
            )
```

**Home Screen where I try to display added Items: **

```
class MyHomePage extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  ConsumerState<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends ConsumerState<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    AsyncValue<List<Item>> asyncValue = ref.watch(allItemsProvider);

    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              const Text(
                'Items List',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: asyncValue.when(
                    error: (error, _) => Text(error.toString()),
                    loading: () => const CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    data: (data) {
                      if (data.isEmpty) return Text('data emtpy'.toUpperCase());
                      final users = data;
                      return ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: users.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              child: Container(
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    border: Border.all(width: 2),
                                    color: Colors.amber),
                                child: ListTile(
                                  leading: Text(
                                    users[index].id!.toString(),
                                    style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 23),
                                  ),
                                  tileColor: Colors.red,
                                  title: Text(
                                    'UserName: ${users[index].name!}',
                                    style: const TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 20,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                                  ),
                                  subtitle:
                                      Text(users[index].items ?? 'Not Set'),
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          });
                    }),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          heroTag: "btn1",
          onPressed: () {
            // AddItemScreen
            Navigator.push(context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const AddUseScreen()));
          },
          child: const Icon(Icons.add),
        )); 
  }
}
```

I have an issue when I added new item to Local SQLite DataBase (additional I do api request to get some property before execute query to database ), the UI does not show me added items, but shows only I reload Screen.

I noticed that, if I add item without request api, the new items appears in the list after navigation immediately.

`FutureOr<void> addItem(Item item) async { ref.read(dataBaseProvider).insertUser(item.copyWith(items: apiItem)); }`

if I add item with request api before add to database, the new items does not appear in the list after navigation immediately, it appears only click reload application.

My questions:

1. How to combine different providers in one method?
2. How to handle navigation,  it must navigate after item added?
3. How it is possible to a loader to button 'Add new Item' while adding new item to database, in another worlds listen changes. I know that there is a listen method in the Riverpod.

Sorry for my  bad english.
If someone helps me it would fantastic.

I tried case 1:

```
final apiFuture = FutureProvider((ref) async {
  return ApiGet().geTitle();
});
```

```
FutureOr<void> addItem(Item user) async {
    final AsyncValue<String> apiItem = ref.watch(apiFuture);
    apiItem.whenData((value) {
      ref.read(dataBaseProvider).insertUser(user.copyWith(items: value));
    });
  }
```

but it does not helped me at all

case 2:

```
FutureOr<void> addItem(Item user) async {
    final value = await Future.wait([ ApiGet().geTitle()]);
    ref.read(dataBaseProvider).insertUser(user.copyWith(items: value.first));
  }
```

the new items does not appear in the list after navigation immediately, it appears only click reload application.
As I understanding correct that, navigation to Item List Screen is faster than the method add Item (with two Futures) works

Comment: Closed found temporary solution: 
   await ref.read(someProvider.notifier).added(newOne).then((_) {
                                if (context.mounted) {
                                  Navigator.pop(context);
                                  ref.invalidate(someProvider);
                                }
                              });